# Too many aurguments to public overloads submenu in vb.net combobox

Tags: vb.net

Too many aurguments to public overloads submenu in vb.net  combobox
error in Function in vb.net combobox

```
Public Function combo(strQuery As String) As List(Of ComboBox)
    Dim objlist As New List(Of ComboBox)
    con.Open()
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    For Each dr In ExecuteReader(strQuery).Rows
        objlist.Add(New ComboBox(Convert.ToInt32(dr.Item(0).ToString()), dr.Item(1).ToString()))
    Next
    con.Close()
    Return objlist
End Function

<Extension>

Public Function ExecuteReader(strQuery As String) As DataTable
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then con.Close()
    con.Open()
    cmd = New SqlCommand(strQuery, con)
    da = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    da.Fill(dt)
    con.Close()
    Return dt
End Function
```

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: Please take the time and make the effort to provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem. ALWAYS provide the relevant code and the actual error message as text, formatted appropriately. Also, specify where in the code the error occurs. There's no call to a `submenu` method in that code so the whole question appears to be nonsense.

Comment: That said, what exactly is confusing about an error message telling you that you are providing too many arguments when calling a method? You can't just pass whatever you like to whatever method you like. The method has parameters and each one has a type. That's what you need to pass when you call the method.

Comment: Can’t remember the syntax off the top of my head, but any reason for the _<extension>_ tag there?  Could that be turning your function into an extension method of string, but then your calling it as if it was a normal function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ComboBox constructor does not take any parameters. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.-ctor?view=windowsdesktop-6.0

I think your function should read

```
Private Class ComboBoxItem
    Public Property Id As Integer
    Public Property Text As String
    Public Sub New(Id As Integer, Text As String)
        Me.Id = Id
        Me.Text = Text
    End Sub
End Class

Public Function GetPopulatedCombo(strQuery As String) As ComboBox
    Dim Combo As ComboBox = New ComboBox
    Combo.DisplayMember = "Text"
    Using DT = ExecuteReader(strQuery)    
        For Each dr In DT.Rows
            Combo.Items.Add(New ComboBoxItem(dr.Item(0),dr.Item(1))
        Next
    End Using
    Return Combo 
End Function
```